# IsNull in VB6 and VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, migration, isnull

I have a code -

```
strTest="    "    
IsNull(Trim(strTest))
```

It returns **False** in VB6 .
I write this code to VB.net 
but

> IsNull(Trim(strTest))

returns **True** .
So,
**IsNull(Trim("    "))**  in VB6 = **??** in VB.net
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `IsNull` function in VB.Net. Instead it has other things like `String.IsNullOrEmpty` function and `String.Empty` property etc. for finding out whether a string is empty or not.

`IsNull` in VB6/VBA means whether an expression contains no valid data. You are getting `False` in vb6 because you have initialized `strTest`. It holds an empty string. You might also want to see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx)

**VB6**

```
IsNull(Trim(strTest))
```

In VB.Net, `IsNullOrEmpty` Indicates whether the specified string is `Nothing` or an `Empty` string.

**VB.NET**

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTest.Trim) Then DoWhatever
If strTest.Trim = String.Empty Then DoWhatever
If strTest.Trim = "" Then DoWhatever      '<~~ Same in VB6 as well
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strTest) Then DoWhatever  '<~~ VB2010 onwards only
```

All these will return `True` in VB.Net because the string `IS` EMPTY. You might want to see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

If your string value is all spaces then either use `strTest.Trim()` before using the first 3 options, or use the 4th option directly which checks whether it is nothing, or empty string or all spaces only.

Comment: `If IsNull(strTest)` in VB6 = `If strTest Is Nothing` in VB.net ?? Is it also right?

Comment: +1 Sid. Nicely explained. @nnnn: Yes that's right. The `IsNull` check can be compared with `Nothing` in VB.NET. But be aware that strings behave a bit differently in VB6 and VB.NET. I always use the `IsNullOrEmpty` check or the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check (as the case may be), rather than a direct `""` string compare or `Nothing` or `String.Empty`. VB.NET internally does a lot of things to make these three things seem similar. I've never felt the use of comparing any string to Nothing till now in vb.net yet.

Comment: @PradeepKumar `I've never felt the use of comparing any string to Nothing till now in vb.net yet.` Me too :) and BTW... Thanks :)